# OpenCvSharp Mat Ptr usage

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I know very litte C++. I am trying to convert code that written C++ to C#. But I cannot convert this code :

```
/* Convert the angle into predefined 3x3 neighbor locations
 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
 | 8 | 7 | 6 |
 */
for( int y = 0; y < grad_dir.rows; y++ ) {
    float * grad_ptr = grad_dir.ptr<float>(y);

    for( int x = 0; x < grad_dir.cols; x++ ) {
        if( grad_ptr[x] != 0 )
            grad_ptr[x] = toBin( grad_ptr[x] );
    }
}
```

toBin:

```
int RobustTextDetection::toBin( const float angle, const int neighbors ) {
    const float divisor = 180.0 / neighbors;
    return static_cast<int>( (( floor(angle / divisor)  - 1) / 2) + 1 ) % neighbors + 1;
}
```

grad_ptr.Ptr returns  IntPtr but it is not array, so compiler is giving error. How can I convert it to C#

Comment: Seems like equivalent of [cv::Mat::ptr](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/1a751d91-8a3a-693b-e592-5fde988f939b.htm) exists in OpenCVSharp. (Also there seems to be some discrepancy, given that in C++ `toBin` is called with a single parameter, but your C# version seems to take 2)

Comment: @DanMašek Yes , I have added toBin C++ code.